# Time complexity of O(log n) nested in another O(log n) loop

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm a bit confused about the time complexity of the following algorithm. I know that inserting into a heap is O(log n) with base 2, but the while loop that it's nested insides seems to be O(log n) with base 3. Would the time complexity be O(log n with base 3) * O(log n with base 2)?

```
i = 1
while i < len(L):
    insert L[i] into heap
    i = i*3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `i` increases exponentially, you will be inserting `floor(log3(L))` elements into `heap`.

Assuming that an insertion is `O(log(n))`, where `n` is the number of elements already in the heap (*not* the array `L`), doing `m` insertions to an initially empty heap will have complexity `O(log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... log (m - 1)) = O(log([m - 1]!) = O(log(m!))`.

According to **Stirling's Approximation**, `ln(n!) = n ln n - n + O(ln n)`.

Substituting in the number of insertions, and ignoring the overshadowed `O(n)` terms, we have:

```
T(L) = O(log([floor(log3(L))]!))
     = O([floor(log3(L))][log(floor(log3(L)))])  // apply Stirling
     = O([log3(L)][log(log3(L))])  // a number rounded down only differs
                                      from its value by less than 1
     = O(log L * log log L)        // base of log only contributes to a constant
```

Comment: Wow, this is a really nice and rigorous explanation. Just one question: this is my first time learning about Stirlings but when you applied it in the second step you just excluded the "- n + O(ln n)". Is that because n log n is the dominant term?

Comment: @Jesse sorry for the late reply, and yes you are correct, because `log n` is asymptotically greater than `O(1)`, so `O(n log n) > O(n)`. [I included the second term `-n` because I have seen example problems where the `n log n` term cancels.]